# Changing multiple class names in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, z-index, addclass, removeclass

I posted on this project I'm working on yesterday and have managed to find a way to get most of the desired effect that I need.  I may be doing this the long way, but here goes what I have and what I need.

This is set up as four boxes, each starting on a different z-index level (40, 60, 80 and 100)  #layer1 being on top.  When the top box is clicked it goes to the back and the three others are brought forward.  When one of the other three boxes are clicked, it is brought forward and the ones in front of it are pushed back.  I've got the .layer1, .layer2, .layer3 and .layer4 functions running this, and it works, but only one time.  Afterwards, things start getting hairy.  I've tried in the changePos function to look up the current z-index value of each box by layer id, then to create an array to hold the values, then a loop to correspond them to the index values I have in place, but it's not coming out right.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {


       function changePos(){

                                    var l1Index = $("#layer1").css('zIndex');
                                    var l2Index = $("#layer2").css('zIndex');
                                    var l3Index = $("#layer3").css('zIndex');
                                    var l4Index = $("#layer4").css('zIndex');

                                    var i;
                                    var layerZindex = new Array();
                                    layerZindex[1] = l1Index;
                                    layerZindex[2] = l2Index;
                                    layerZindex[3] = l3Index;
                                    layerZindex[4] = l4Index;

                                    for (i=1;i<4;i++)
                                        {
                                        if(layerZindex[i] == 40){
                                            alert( "class layer" + i + "= 40, is now #layer4");
                                            $("#layer4").removeClass();
                                            $("#layer4").addClass("layer" + [i] + " zindex" + [i]);
                                            }
                                        else if(layerZindex[i] == 60){
                                            alert( "layer" + i + "= 60, is now #layer3");
                                            $("#layer3").removeClass();
                                            $("#layer3").addClass("layer" + [i] + " zindex" + [i]);
                                            }
                                        else if(layerZindex[i] == 80){
                                            alert( "layer" + i + "= 80, is now #layer2");
                                            $("#layer2").removeClass();
                                            $("#layer2").addClass("layer" + [i] + " zindex" + [i]);
                                            }
                                        else if(layerZindex[i] == 100){
                                            alert( "layer" + i + "= 100, is now #layer1");
                                            $("#layer1").removeClass();
                                            $("#layer1").addClass("layer" + [i] + " zindex" + [i]);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

        $(".layer1").click(function() {

            $(".layer1").animate({
                opacity: "0.6",
                left: "-120px",
                top: "-90px",
                zIndex: "40"
            }, 850);
            $(".layer2").animate({
                opacity: "1",
                left: "40px",
                top: "30px",
                zIndex: "100"
            }, 550);
            $(".layer3").animate({
                opacity: "0.6",
                left: "40px",
                top: "30px",
                zIndex: "80"
            }, 700);
            $(".layer4").animate({
                opacity: "0.6",
                left: "40px",
                top: "30px",
                zIndex: "60"
            }, 850);
            $("#siteDesc1").animate({
                opacity: "0"
            }, 600);
            $("#siteDesc2").animate({
                opacity: "1"
            }, 600);
            changePos();
        });


        $(".layer2").click(function() {
            $(".layer2").animate({
                opacity: "1",
                left: "40px",
                top: "30px",
                zIndex: "100"
            }, 400);
            $(".layer1").animate({
                opacity: "0.6",
                left: "-40px",
                top: "-30px",
                zIndex: "80"
            }, 550);
            $("Descriptions").animate({
                opacity: "0"
            }, 600);
            $("#siteDesc1").animate({
                opacity: "0"
            }, 600);
            $("#siteDesc2").animate({
                opacity: "1"
            }, 600);
            changePos();
        });

        $(".layer3").click(function() {
            $(".layer3").animate({
                opacity: "1",
                left: "80px",
                top: "60px",
                zIndex: "100"
            }, 400);
            $(".layer1").animate({
                opacity: "0.6",
                left: "-40px",
                top: "-30px",
                zIndex: "80"
            }, 400);
            $(".layer2").animate({
                opacity: "0.6",
                left: "-40px",
                top: "-30px",
                zIndex: "60"
            }, 550);
            $("Descriptions").animate({
                opacity: "0"
            }, 600);
            $("#siteDesc1").animate({
                opacity: "0"
            }, 600);
            $("#siteDesc3").animate({
                opacity: "1"
            }, 600);
            changePos();
        });

        $(".layer4").click(function() {
            $(".layer4").animate({
                opacity: "1",
                left: "120px",
                top: "90px",
                zIndex: "100"
            }, 400);
            $(".layer1").animate({
                opacity: "0.6",
                left: "-40px",
                top: "-30px",
                zIndex: "80"
            }, 400);
            $(".layer2").animate({
                opacity: "0.6",
                left: "-40px",
                top: "-30px",
                zIndex: "60"
            }, 550);
            $(".layer3").animate({
                opacity: "0.6",
                left: "-40px",
                top: "-30px",
                zIndex: "40"
            }, 700);
            $("Descriptions").animate({
                opacity: "0"
            }, 600);
            $("#siteDesc1").animate({
                opacity: "0"
            }, 600);
            $("#siteDesc4").animate({
                opacity: "1"
            }, 600);
            changePos();
        });

    });​
        </script>

Here is my html

    <div id="sites">
        <div id="layer1" class="layer1 zindex1">
        </div>
        <div id="layer2" class="layer2 zindex2">
        </div>      
        <div id="layer3" class="layer3 zindex3">
        </div>      
        <div id="layer4" class="layer4 zindex4">
        </div>
    </div>
```

IN the css, the #layer id currently drives the color, the layer class drives the size, opacity and positioning type(absolute), and the zindex class drives the position using margins.

My problem is that I need to run this on a loop, where the layer class is reissued according to which box ends up with the highest z-index after the function has run.

Also, any opinion as to whether there is a more efficient way to run this effect?

:And update on my progress here, it's so close.  I haven't figured out what is causing the problem but the behavior seems to carry out the original transition, no problem, but then gets hung up when I run changePos.  It carries out the function designated to the new box on top rather than renaming it.  Upon another click it carries out the function of the .layer1 box, then alternates between the two.  changePos function does appear to be renaming the classes, but somewhere it gets muddled up.  Perhaps by the layerZindex array?  I'm looking in to that next.

Comment: Those class names look familiar. :)

Comment: Ha yes Barmar.  I greatly appreciate your help, but as I moved along I realized more and more that this thing was something a lot bigger.  I thought it'd be more appropriate to ask this as a new question since it's so much different than last nights.

Comment: I think what I might need to do here is create a function that is called within each click function, that either changes the class name of an item based on z-index position or somehow calculates it by the last clicked item.  Not really sure how to do either one of these though.

Comment: I haven't really studied your problem closely, but I'm pretty sure there must be a logic to it that allows you to write a single function that figures out from the layer number how to adjust the styles of all the divs.

Comment: I've figured out that I need to create a function that pulls the value of the z-index, matches them with the values I have set (100, 80, 60 and 40), and changes the class according to the z-index value.  Might I need to use a case statement to do that?  I tried using index.sort() to put these in order, when I tested it with alert though, it doesn't seem to be coming up right.  The order that it shows, no matter which box I chose is 100, 40, 60, 80.  I've added my edits above with changePos function.

Comment: As I said, I haven't really figured out the logic of your application. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: Oh that's okay.  I'm updating this as I feel I make progress.  It's still buggy, but it feels like I'm close.  By logic of the application, do you mean that you don't understand what it's supposed to do, or that the manner that I'm writing this is odd and doesn't make much sense?  I'm sure the latter is true as it's been a while since I've done much with javascript and was far from an expert then

Comment: `sort()` uses a lexicographical sort, rather than numeric. To sort by number: `sort(function(a,b) { return a-b; });` See: [`Array.sort()` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: I know what you're trying to accomplish, I just haven't thought about the details enough to understand how to generate the appropriate values algorithmically.  I'm sure there's a pattern, I just don't feel like working it out.

Comment: what it supposed to do ? :)

Comment: seems you want to click on top layer and move it to the end of stack ?

Comment: Hi eicto, yes that's regarding the first box.  On the other three boxes I'd like to pull the selected box to the top and push the other 1-3 boxes back.  Like I said, it seems like this is close, but it's still messing up after the first click.  I'm re editing the above code to reflect where I have it now.

Comment: Well, I've racked my brain trying to get this to work right.  From my understanding, this changePos() should work right.  It checks each id, looks for the z-index, then changes the class according to the id's z placement.  But it's getting all haywire somewhere along the way, and I can't figure out why.  The only thing I can figure is that perhaps it's conflicting with the css property changes that I make to each class?  Is there a better way to do this, or am I on the right track?

Comment: For us to answer your last comment: we *need to know what you're trying to do*. Reading your question, and your comments, leaves me none the wiser. When the user clicks on the element (which element) what should happen? How does the class-name relate to what happens? How is the `z-index` supposed to change? Please: edit your question and *clearly* explain, step-by-step, what should happen.

Comment: I'm curious, how many times do you run the function changePos() in your script? It appears you're calling it from within itself a number of times over, rebinding your events each time...

Comment: I think you should give `changePos` some parameters instead of letting it try to find what to do itself

Comment: David Thomas, I'm sorry, I had thought that I had originally explained it's purpose, but had overlooked it.  I put it in at the top.  I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: David Barker, the changePos() is self contained and called within the #layer functions.  For a second I had to do a doubletake, but am pretty sure it's as it should be.

Comment: Bergi, what information do you think I should pass through as parameters?  The 40, 60, 80 and 100?  I think I'll have to find the z-index value within the function as it's supposed to change depending on which item I click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through outside sources I got some help on this.  This is what I've got.

```
function changePos() {
        // References to the z-index levels, this makes our code shorter and more efficient
        var levels = {40 : 4, 60 : 3, 80 : 2, 100 : 1};
        var i = 1;
        $('[id^=layer]').each(function() {
            // Get the element z-index level
            var zIndexLevel = $(this).css('zIndex');

            // Set the respective element class
            if (levels[zIndexLevel]) {
                $('#layer' + i).attr('class', 'layer' + levels[zIndexLevel]);
                $('#SiteDescriptions' + i).animate({opacity: "1"}, 500);

                $('#SiteDescriptions' + !i).animate({opacity: "0"}, 500);
            //alert( levels[zIndexLevel] + ":" + zIndexLevel);
            i++;
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps for anyone who might have the same problem